# Keyboard dismiss very buggy on tableview interactive

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, lag, uikeyboard

I have a textfield inside tableviewcontroller which is inside tabbarcontroller when i drag the keyboard down it lags right before dismiss. I am using the interactive mode so keyboard dismisses on drag.

```
class TempTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
        tableView.register(TitleTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! TitleTableViewCell
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}
```

my tableviewcell has a uitextfield. however when i drag the keyboard down it lags before being dismissed

```
class TitleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    let titleView: UITextField = {
       let textView = UITextField()
        textView.text = "Add your title ... "
        textView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
//        textView.sizeToFit()
//        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
        return textView
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.contentView.addSubview(titleView)
        setTitleViewConstraints()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    func setTitleViewConstraints(){
        titleView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor,constant: 10).isActive=true
        titleView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor,constant: -10).isActive=true
        titleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive=true
        titleView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor,constant: -10).isActive=true
    }

}

class tabBarViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let homeViewController = HomeViewController()
        homeViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "home-tab")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), selectedImage: nil)
        let discoverViewController = DiscoverViewController()
        discoverViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "discover-tab")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), selectedImage: nil)
        let notificationViewController = NotificationViewController()
        notificationViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "notification-tab")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), selectedImage: nil)
        let tempViewController = TempTableViewController()
        tempViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "profile-tab")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), selectedImage: nil)


        let tabBarList = [homeViewController, discoverViewController,notificationViewController,tempViewController ]

            self.viewControllers = tabBarList.map { viewController in

            return UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)

        }
    }

}
```

this is the appdelegate class where tabbarcontroller is selected based on user credentials

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        UINavigationBar.appearance().isOpaque = false
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .white
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        checkUserStatus()
        return true
    }

    func checkUserStatus(){
        window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.setupRootViewController(viewController: UIViewController())
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener {[weak self] auth,user in
            if(user != nil){
                self?.setupRootViewController(viewController: tabBarViewController())
            }else{
                self?.setupRootViewController(viewController: UINavigationController(rootViewController: WelcomeViewController()))
            }
        }
    }
    private func setupRootViewController(viewController: UIViewController) {
        self.window!.rootViewController = viewController
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Just an update. This is happening even if i remove the tabbarcontroller and just load the tempViewController which has the textfield. Very strange

Comment: Also happening on the simulator. I tried making a new project and it still happens

Comment: cant u try .onDrag instead of .interactive

Comment: If you can share your project on github I'll take a look

Comment: .onDrag gives the same error. The git is https://github.com/ahmed14642/keyboardBug. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: What do you mean by buggy keyboard, at bottom of screen keyboard suggestion is shown for a seconds and hidden ..Are you refering to that..?

Comment: yes the suggestion of the keyboards hangs there at the bottom.This does not happen with other apps

Comment: seem this bug come from `tableView.keyboardDismissMode` in iOS 13. When using the normal way like `view.endEditing(true)` in `scrollViewDidScroll`, keyboard dismiss smoother. This bug don't happen in iOS 12.2 and before

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I launched your application with **iOS 12** and it works correctly.

This solution may help you with **iOS 13**.

1) Add the observer in `viewDidLoad()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
```

2) Add function `getKeyboardWindow()`

```
private func getKeyboardWindow() -> UIWindow? {

    for window in UIApplication.shared.windows {

        if (NSStringFromClass(type(of: window).self) == "UIRemoteKeyboardWindow") {
            return window
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

3) Add function `keyboardWillHide(notification:)`

```
@objc private func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {

    guard let keyboardWindow: UIWindow = getKeyboardWindow() else { return }

    let screenWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let screenHeight: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

    keyboardWindow.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
}
```

P.S. However, I don't like to fix issues this way.

But in this case, I don't know a more elegant solution.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

doe,

What you are doing is right, **I don't see that as an issue**, even contacts app have the same feature like yours (i.e text field in table view). Contact app also behaves the same way

Find the comparison screen recording of contact app and yours,

[image: Contacts App] . [image: Your App]

If you still want to fix it, I would suggest to remove auto-correction, If your requirement allows.

```
textView.autocorrectionType = .no
```

Answer (score 0):

Because tableviews inherit from ScrollViews you can override a scrollview method "scrollViewWillEndDragging" and call endEditing(true)

```
  override func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
                self.view.endEditing(true)

        }
```

and you can even do more
you can detect when the user scroll up or down using the velocity parameter of the function signature like this :

**up**

```
 override func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        if(velocity.y > 0){
            self.view.endEditing(true)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

**down**

```
 override func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
            if(velocity.y < 0){
                self.view.endEditing(true)
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
```

Comment: That is the solution I am using currently. however that does not have the same effect as .interactive or .drag since you can't scroll with the keyboard presented. Keyboard should only be dismissed when its swiped down like it happens with .interactive or .drag

Comment: Maybe  you can try NotificationCenter for view, here is my gist;
https://gist.github.com/erdemildiz/7aeb71709651cec96d8dc3dffc766518
 @j.doe

Answer (score 0):

You can try setup empty view `textView.inputAccessoryView = UIView()`